# How can I create input fields like on any Shopify checkout page?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to create 3 input fields just like the ones on any Shopify checkout page.

Here are the functions for the input fields:

1. making spaces every 4 digits in the credit card number input field; number-only field; limiting it to 16 characters
2. creating a slash in after 2 digits for the expiration date field; limiting it to 8 characters; number-only field

This one would allows the user to do 2 things:

1. Write a number from 2-9, which automatically writes a slash afterwards.

It should look like [this.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6tzmfjwq0flsrn/date%20field%202.mov?dl=0)

2. Write either 10, 11, or 12, which automatically writes a slash afterwards.

It should look like [this.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8pa90gmuczdtkp/date%20field%201.mov?dl=0)

See how it writes a slash automatically right after the second number? It only does that if you type in "/" or a second number for the month.

Here is what I'm playing with:

```js
/*$('#number').on('keypress',function(){
var val = this.value;
var firstVal = val.slice(0,2);    
var secondVal = val.slice(2,6);  
var finalVal = firstVal+"/"+secondVal; 
console.log(finalVal); 
this.value = finalVal; 
}); */

$('#number').on('keypress', function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 2) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 2) + '/' + this.value.slice(3, this.value.length)
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#number").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl/cmd+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
             // Allow: Ctrl/cmd+C
            (e.keyCode == 67 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
             // Allow: Ctrl/cmd+X
            (e.keyCode == 88 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="number" maxlength="7" placeholder="MM/YY" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

But the problem I'm having here is that you can't even type a slash.

Thanks in advance,
Josiah

Comment: Is it required that you write this functionality yourself, or is a plugin such as [MDL](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learning-material-design-lite-text-fields--cms-24614) or one of [these](http://www.learningjquery.com/2016/03/10-jquery-credit-card-form-plugins) acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for responding @JavaSpyder. As long as the end result is what I posted in my original post, I can use anything. I will definitely check out those references, though! I really appreciate it :)